# django-rest-framework CRUD many models in same view

Tags: models, crud, django-rest-framework

I would like to be able to CRUD many models in the same API View.

In this case there are User and UserProfile Models in the same API View.

#### My Serializers

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('expected_calories',)


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    expected_calories = serializers.

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'expected_calories')


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

#### Then my views

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

#### GET Api Call to

> /api/v1/user/2/

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/2/", 
    "username": "jsalchichon", 
    "email": "jsalchichon@example.com", 
    "first_name": "John", 
    "last_name": "Salchichon", 
    "expected_calories": 0
}
```

But when I try to update the expected_calories field to 2500, The field is not updated.

Is this the right way to do this? What else should I do to be able to update the expected_calories of the UserProfile Model?

Thanks to you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### I just did this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    expected_calories = serializers.Field(source='userprofile.expected_calories')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'expected_calories')

    def validate_expected_calories(self, attrs, source):
        expected_calories = self.data.get('expected_calories')
        if not isinstance(expected_calories, int):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("expected_calories must be an integer")
        attrs['expected_calories'] = expected_calories or self.object.userprofile.expected_calories
        return attrs

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
        super(UserViewSet, self).post_save(obj, created)
        expected_calories = self.request.DATA.get('expected_calories')
        if isinstance(expected_calories, int):
            obj.userprofile.expected_calories = self.request.DATA.get('expected_calories',
                                                                      obj.userprofile.expected_calories)
            obj.userprofile.save()
```

Not sure if it's the right way to handle this but it works.